# Evaluation $LABEL inside of erb part in fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, fixtures

Looking for a way to DRY fixtures a bit.
Let's say we have some data.yml. There is a part there, that can be referenced from $LABEL. Here is an exapmle:

```
DEFAULTS: &DEFAULTS
  state: $LABEL
  score: 99
one:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  uuid: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:one, :uuid) %>
two:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
  uuid: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:two, :uuid) %>
```

Is there any way to DRY it. I want something like this:

```
DEFAULTS: &DEFAULTS
  state: $LABEL
  score: 99
  uuid: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify($LABEL, :uuid) %>
one:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
two:
  <<: *DEFAULTS
```

But it's not possible because $LABEL is not evaluated here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the ERB tags are processed before `$LABEL` is replaced.

You can see the string replacement happening here in ActiveRecord:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d514ce9199fac58e569482dc901e53d0526abdf7/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L656

In my case, I quickly wrote another method at line 663 underneath the primary key creation, which means I can use `$PRIMARY_KEY` in my YAML file rather than `$LABEL`.

```
# interpolate the primary key
row.each do |key, value|
  row[key] = value.gsub("$PRIMARY_KEY", row[primary_key_name].to_s) if value.is_a?(String)
end
```

Obviously not a long-term solution, but leaving it here in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with this same issue, and really don't want to switch to factories just for few cases where this would be helpful.

That being said, it looks like the uuid's are not your primary key, is that the case? If you are able to make the uuids your primary key (we do this now in Postgres) then what you are doing is actually not needed as Rails will properly identify the associations on the ids. You could try setting the `primary_key` on the model class itself to use the uuid column and since fixtures will introspect that should work and avoid needing to evaluate $LABEL and dry this up.

Comment: Sad, but I can't make uuids as PK in this particular case. But thanks, this may help someday )